# Easter egg in cabin baggage on Ryanair

Tags: air-travel, uk, hand-luggage, prohibited-items

I'm flying from the UK to Spain soon with Ryanair and wanted to carry an Easter egg in my hand luggage. Is this possible?
I know Christmas crackers are not allowed but didn't find info about Easter treats.

Cheers

Comment: is it just chocolate, or is there a creamy filling? serious question. The rule isn't to do with being a holiday treat, it's just that being a holiday treat doesn't exempt an item. Christmas crackers are explosives. Cream eggs may violate the liquids-and-gels rules. Chocolate should be fine.

Comment: or maybe it is a real hard-cooked _egg_? colored or painted?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as unclear? It's completely clear, even if you don't understand why it's being asked.

Comment: It is usually the departure airport, or its country, which sets the rules on what you can take into the plane. The UK rules are well known.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the "not clear" part is whether this is chocolate, an actual hen's egg, something cream or caramel filled, how large it is, etc etc.

Comment: @KateGregory Sure but it's trivial to cover all the options in an answer, which makes, and that makes the question _more_ useful to future visitors, rather not less. Also, for somebody flying from the UK, "Easter egg" means chocolate egg about 99% of the time.

Comment: If it's a hollow chocolate egg, it may crack open, due to the low pressure in flight, and thus higher relative pressure inside

Answer (score 7):

Christmas crackers aren't allowed because they contain explosives. Airlines probably mention them explicitly because lots of people were getting them confiscated at security.

There's no reason you can't bring an Easter egg, as long as it doesn't break any of the general rules of carriage for hand baggage. The most likely one would be the liquids/gels rule, if it has some sort of liquidy/cream/something filling.